# How to get data of the selected range in Excel Javascript API?

Tags: excel, javascript-api-for-office

I am trying to write a Excel plugin where I get the data from the currently selected ranges and then serialize it to be sent over rest request.  Here is what I got:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRanges();

    selectedRange.load('address');

    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        //selectedRange.address is now available to use
        var selectedRangeJSON = selectedRange.toJSON();

    }).catch(function (error) {
        //handle
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    //handle
});
```

The selectedRangeJSON  return an object defined here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.interfaces.rangeareasdata?view=office-js

How do get the actual value from this object so I can serialize it?

Comment: For Reference --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76584702/unable-to-get-selected-range-when-column-selected-excel-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out, this fully works:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();

    selectedRange.load("text");

    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        var selectedRangeJSON = JSON.stringify(selectedRange.text);

    }).catch(function (error) {
        //handle
        dialog.openMsgBox(error);
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    //handle
    dialog.openMsgBox(error);
});
```

Comment: I'd think you would load `values` not `text`