# Unable to Get Selected Range when Column Selected - Excel Javascript

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm wondering if I found another bug using "entire column ranges". I'm looking to capture the selected range values and generally, when I select a range, I just select the column header say "A" and it selects the entire column. But, after wasting time testing, I realized that my code only works when I don't select columns.

Is this a bug or is my code incorrect?

Is there a way to drill down to the "Selected Range with Values"? Like how you can do `getUsedRange(true)`, the `true` being "only Used Range with Values".

**This works:**

```
console.log('A1 Select')
var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
ws.getRange("A1").select()
await context.sync()

var range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
range.load(['values']);
await context.sync();

var firstSelectedCellValue = range.values[0][0];
console.log('firstSelectedCellValue:')
console.log(firstSelectedCellValue)
await context.sync();
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
console.log('A Col Select')
ws.getRange("A:A").select()
await context.sync();

var range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
range.load(['values']);
await context.sync();

var firstSelectedCellValue = range.values[0][0];
console.log('firstSelectedCellValue:')
console.log(firstSelectedCellValue)
await context.sync();
```

**Here is the Output:**

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
index.html
Dev_Mode = true
Agave.HostCall.IssueCall
Agave.HostCall.ReceiveResponse
commands.js:Office.onReady
Agave.HostCall.IssueCall
commandsfunc
A1 Select
Agave.HostCall.ReceiveResponse
firstSelectedCellValue:
Header A
A Col Select
Error: 
TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference",
      message: "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference",
      name: "TypeError",
      number: -2146823281,
      stack: "TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:3000/yo/dist/commands.js:1:1453)
   at h (http://localhost:3000/yo/dist/globals.js:1:1139)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:3000/yo/dist/globals.js:1:948)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:3000/yo/dist/globals.js:1:1583)
   at n (http://localhost:3000/yo/dist/commands.js:1:52)
   at u (http://localhost:3000/yo/dist/commands.js:1:265)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:3000/yo/dist/polyfill.js:1:76119)
   at e (http://localhost:3000/yo/dist/polyfill.js:1:31843)",
      Symbol()_7.l9joxxhdsmj: undefined,
      Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)_j.l9joxxhdsja: undefined
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the fact that I couldn't read full range values really had nothing to do with `selectedRange`. I've been down this path before and basically was told by Devs they don't care that it doesn't work as you'd expect because it would be a slow operation and that the users code needs to be adjusted, not the API.

You can NOT read a full column or rows values. It will return `null`. You need to check for `isEntireRow` or `isEntireColumn` and then remove one row/column from range then check. You can then run another operation to check that removed single row/column (this is better then fixing the API according to Devs..)

I had plans to drill down to the `usedRange` if the user had selected entire Column/Row anyway, so the below is what I ended up with which I'll wrap into a function to get the "Selected Range".

```
var Load_Opts_Arr = ['rowCount','rowIndex', 'columnCount','columnIndex', 'values','isEntireColumn','isEntireRow']  

var rng = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
rng.load(Load_Opts_Arr);
await context.sync();

if (rng.isEntireColumn == true || rng.isEntireRow == true) {
    var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var Used_Rng_And_Props = ws.getUsedRange(true)
    Used_Rng_And_Props.load(['rowCount','rowIndex', 'columnCount','columnIndex'] );
    await context.sync();
}

if (rng.isEntireColumn == true) {
    var rng = ws.getRangeByIndexes(Used_Rng_And_Props.rowIndex, rng.columnIndex, Used_Rng_And_Props.rowCount, rng.columnCount)
    rng.load(Load_Opts_Arr);
    await context.sync();
}

if (rng.isEntireRow == true) {
    var rng = ws.getRangeByIndexes(rng.rowIndex, Used_Rng_And_Props.columnIndex, rng.rowCount, Used_Rng_And_Props.columnCount - rng.columnIndex)
    rng.load(Load_Opts_Arr);
    await context.sync();
}
```